# How can I continue executing code after a try/catch block catches an exception?

Tags: java

```
try
{
someTask();
someTask2();
someTask3();
someTask4();
someTask5();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
// log the error
}
```

if one of my task fails, I want a log of what happened, but I want to continue running the rest of the tasks. I know I can surround each task method with its own try/catch, but is there a cleaner way so I don't have so many try/catch blocks?

Comment: You can catch and handle the exceptions and log them individually _inside_ of each method then instead of throwing them all the way up.

Comment: Write a separate Try catch block for each task.

Comment: @Apoorva sahay He specifically says in the question he already knows he can do that, and is asking for a better solution if it exists.

Comment: @user6800688 are your task interdependent? If not why cant you create a separate thread for each and handle exception at the thread level.

Comment: You could take a look at functional interfaces perhaps and add each method to a collection that you loop over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your task return `void` and take no parameters you could create a functional interface :

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Task {
    void perform() throws Exception;
}
```

then create a helper method that will handle logging and will take `Task` as parameter :

```
private static void invoke(Task task) {
    try {
        task.perform();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log here    
    }
}
```

And then use it :

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        invoke(MyClass::someTask);
        invoke(MyClass::someTask1);
    }

    private static void someTask() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Task 1");
    }

    private static void someTask1() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Exception");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I nuked my comment, it wasn't adding anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

The best way for this is for each of your methods to execute with a `try`/`catch` inside.

```
void someMethod(){
 try{
//code of method 1
 }catch(Exception e){
  e.printstackTrace()
 }
}
```

and then call them all without `try`/`catch`.

```
someTask();
someTask2();
someTask3();
someTask4();
someTask5();
```

Now if one fails, the other will just continue.

Answer (score 0):

To run the rest of tasks, you have to put **EVERY** task in a separate ‘try’ block. It is a clean way to do so. Otherwise, how will you know which task failed and how will you debug it?

Also, It is considered as a good practice to put every expected error separately in catch block, starting from more specific and finishing with more general. So that you can immediately understand what what problem has happened and save time on debugging

```
try {
    someTask1;
}catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// log the error
}catch (Exception e) {
// log the error
}

try {
    someTask2;
}catch (ArithmeticException e) {
// log the error
}catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
// log the error
}catch (Exception e) {
// log the error
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe using a recursive method:

```
public void myMethod (int state){

 try
 {

  switch(state) {
    case 1:
      state+=1;
      someTask();
      myMethod(state);
      break;
    case 2:
      state+=1;
      someTask2();
      myMethod(state);
      break;
    case 3:
      state+=1;
      someTask3();
      myMethod(state);
      break;
    default:
      state=-1;
}

 }
  catch (Exception e)
 {
 // If some task had an exception, this catch call the next task, because the state variable incremented.
  myMethod(state);
 }

public static void main (String[] Args){

myMethod(1);

}

}
```

Comment: While it looks like this might work, its not a good idea to do something like this.  There is a lot of unnecessary recursion going on and other general badness.

Comment: Our work is find a solution to a problem. Maybe this is not the best solution, obviously the best is use try/catch block inside each method. However, this solution works perfectly and solves the problem. What general badness? It is simple. Please, try my solution and later post a comment.