# Continue after a thrown exception

Tags: java, exception, throw

I have a program that reads lines from csv file. I want to get number of errors (number of all corrupted columns). The program works as:

```
For each line : 
try {

checkColumn1 method () --> May Throw myException 
checkColumn2 method () --> May Throw myException 
checkColumn3 method () --> May Throw myException 
  ....
  ....
checkLastColumnCSV method () --> May Throw myException 

}catch (myException object){
  countErrors ++;

}
```

My program stops at the first exception thrown by a check method, but I want the program to continue executing until the last Checkcolumn method in order to calculate the number of errors on all columns.

I'm working with Java 6 (in an old project), so I cannot use the functional interface.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I continue executing code after a try/catch block catches an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58206563/how-can-i-continue-executing-code-after-a-try-catch-block-catches-an-exception)

Comment: Thank you Yes I'm working with JAVA 6 (in an old project) So I cannot use the Functionnal Interface

Comment: is method() always the same method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround each call to `checkColumnx` with a `try - catch` block.

Comment: do you think this is the only solution we can have? I have several methods, is there a way treat the whole block